# M2 Category Permissions

Tags: magento2, category

Maybe it's just me, but I can't for the life of me find where category permissions exist on 2.0 EE
Even in the new user guide- the only time category permissions is mentioned is in the private sales/events section. Am I missing something here?

1.x documentation:
http://merch.docs.magento.com/ee/user_guide/catalog/category-permissions-configure.html

Comment: Please, do not post EE issues here. Please use the partner portal for reporting issues.